# jQuery Click on an outside element to move unordered list items up or down that contain checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, checked

I need a "Move Up" button and a "Move Down" button that will move list items (that contain checkboxes that are checked) up in the list by 1 place or down by 1 place depending on which button they click. I've seen several posts that deal with similar situations but none of them seem to cover exactly what I need. I would like to stick with the primary jquery.js file.

```
                <ul id="theList">
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <span><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />Checkbox 1</span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <span><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />Checkbox 2</span></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <span><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />Checkbox 3</span></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" id="moveUp">Move Up</a>
                <a href="#" id="moveDown">Move Down</a>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('#moveUp').click(function() {
    return !$('#theList li :checked').closest('li').insertBefore(this.prev());
});

$('#moveDown').click(function() {
    return !$('#theList li :checked').closest('li').insertAfter(this.next());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7cg1hu9/)

```
$('#moveUp').click(function() {
    var $checkedElement = $('#theList li :checked');
    $checkedElement.closest('li').insertBefore($checkedElement.closest('li').prev());
});

$('#moveDown').click(function() {
    var $checkedElement = $('#theList li :checked');
    $checkedElement.closest('li').insertAfter($checkedElement.closest('li').next());
});
```

A few notes..

- You were using a jQuery method on a non-jQuery object `this.prev()`/`this.next()`. It should have been `$(this).prev()`/`$(this).next()`.
- `$(this)` in the current scope referred to the up/down elements. You don't want to change the positions of the checkbox elements based on the up/down button indexes. You need to change the positions relative to the checkbox elements, therefore you would use something like `$checkedElement.closest('li').prev()`.

If you want this to work when moving multiple checkbox elements, you can use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6pg2vcf/)

```
$('#moveUp').click(function() {
    var $checkedElement = $('#theList li :checked');
    $checkedElement.each(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').insertBefore($(this).closest('li').prev());
    });
});

$('#moveDown').click(function() {
    var $checkedElement = $('#theList li :checked');
    $($checkedElement.get().reverse()).each(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').insertAfter($(this).closest('li').next());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @JoshCrozier this worked great! I also appreciate the added notes. Very Thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#moveUp').click(function() {
    $('#theList li :checked').each(function() {
       var li = $(this).closest('li');
       var previous = li.prev();
       // avoid having the selected elements move over each other
       if (previous.length > 0 && previous.find(':checked').length <= 0)
           li.detach().insertBefore(previous);
    });
});

$('#moveDown').click(function() {
    // need to iterate in reverse order - starting from the last
    var selected = $('#theList li :checked');
    var reverse = $(selected.get().reverse());
    reverse.each(function() {
       var li = $(this).closest('li');
       var next = li.next();
       // avoid having the selected elements move over each other
       if (next.length > 0 && next.find(':checked').length <= 0)
           li.detach().insertAfter(next);
    });
});
```